# How to get email address when user is authenticated with Google Oauth2 and people.me

Tags: php, email, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I'm new to php and the google api, I'm trying to get the email address when the user sing in with Google+, I get all the User info using $plus->people->get("me") but when I try to get the email address it fails with this error:

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: value

here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/src");

require_once 'Google/Client.php';

require_once 'Google/Service/Plus.php';

$client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$redirect_uri = 'http://www.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/pruebas.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");

$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Pruebas</title></head>
<body>
<?php if (isset($authUrl)) {
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'><img src='logogoo/Red-signin-Medium-base-32dp.png'></a>";
} else {
    print "<a class='logout' href='pruebas.php?logout'>Cerrar:</a>";
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $me = $plus->people->get("me");

    print "<br>ID: {$me['id']}\n<br>";
    print "Display Name: {$me['displayName']}\n<br>";
    print "Image Url: {$me['image']['url']}\n<br>";
    print "Url: {$me['url']}\n<br>";
    $name3 = $me['name']['givenName'];
    echo "Nombre: $name3 <br>"; //Everything works fine until I try to get the email
    $correo = ($me['emails']['value']);
    echo $correo;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I just what to get the account email address from $me to store it on my app.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*$me['emails']* is an Array, not a Hash. So add an *[0]* for choosing the first Mailadress:

```
$correo = ($me['emails'][0]['value']);
```

Now it should work fine...