# How do I retrieve user's email from Google

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I am using the Google client library in PHP.
I am successfully authenticated.
Missing a simple thing (I added the right scope). How do I retrieve 
the user's email after I finish the auth process.
Below is what I have:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(MYCLIENTID);
$client->setClientSecret(MYSECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(SOMEURLINMYSYSTEM);
$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL);
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);//I have the right code, and I am being authenticated

//TODO Get from google the user's email ?????????
```

I am using the PHP library here: 
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469433/how-to-get-email-address-when-user-is-authenticated-with-google-oauth2-and-peopl ?

Comment: looks like it , yes, my question is cleaner though, so I'll keep it

Answer (score 5):

oops, just found it:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(MYCLIENTID);
$client->setClientSecret(MYSECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(SOMEURLINMYSYSTEM);
$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL);
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);//I have the right code, and I am being authenticated

$client->authenticate($code);
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$person = $plus->people->get('me');
var_dump($person);
```

Comment: Nowhere i could find `Google_Service_Oauth2` was the correct service to use.. had to find it in code. Did you find an overview somewhere or searched in code as well?

Comment: more than a year ago...I am pretty sure I either looked in their developer site examples or found some example someware. Be aware this might be an old version of the current library and API might have changed. Which can account why u not seeing it in the documents.

Answer (score 5):

Much more simple, you can do it like this:

```
$user = $service->userinfo->get();

echo $user->name;
echo $user->id;
echo $user->email;
echo $user->link;
echo $user->picture;
```

Comment: What is $service variable here?

Comment: @kewlashu please look carefully at the original question and you'll find the variable there...

Answer (score 2):

```
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
$person = $plus->people->get('me');
$email = ($person['emails'][0]['value']);
```

For this to work, also don't forget scopes:

```
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
// $client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Google OAuth 2 - Get User Email**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::USERINFO_EMAIL);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::USERINFO_PROFILE);

$tokeninfo = $client->verifyIdToken();
echo $tokeninfo->name;
echo $tokeninfo->email;
```

**Update:** Seems like this is available only during valid "access token" (first login).

If you have setAccessType("offline") and setApprovalPrompt("auto"), then "name" property will not be later available and you need to use Google Plus like mentioned in above posts.